# Change display name per configuration

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to change the display name of my iPhone app per configuration (debug/release/adhoc)? I've set it up so that I can install adhoc builds side-by-side with a development build or a released build but I would like to be able to know which version/configuration I'm running when I look at the display name of the app on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to target settings (Project->Edit active target).
2. Choose appropriate configuration (Debug/Release).
3. Change `Product name` to whatever you want.