# Change display name per configuration in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

Is there a way to change the display name of my iPhone app per configuration (debug/release/adhoc)? I've set it up so that I can install adhoc builds side-by-side with a development build or a released build but I would like to be able to know which version/configuration I'm running when I look at the display name of the app on my phone.

I realized that I asked [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121444/change-display-name-per-configuration) in the regular iPhone forum but now this one is specific to MonoTouch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was create a .plist file for each configuration type: dev.Info.plist, qa.Info.plist, prod.Info.plist. In the .plist files set the key for "Bundle display name" to the name that you want for that configuration. Add a before-build action to each configuration (Project -> Options -> Custom Commands) to replace the Info.plist file in the root of your project.

Just make sure not to check in the .plist file in the root of your project into your VCS and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks to Jason for the tip. But here's the full blown answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same answer in MonoTouch

MonoDevelop --> Project --> Project Options --> iPhone Application --> "Display Name"

I don't know of a way to easily change that automatically per build type - you could possibly setup a custom build action that would do this for you.

Comment: Yeah. I thought that there would be a way since you can do it in Xcode. But I guess not.